# Pyramid numbers in Python

Tags: python, numbers

There is an exercise. If the number has odd number of digits, and the middle digit is the highest and the left and right digits are smaller from one another, then that number is called pyramid number. For example: 14532, 26831, 36751 The user should input 5 digit number. If the inputted number is pyramid number then output “Pyramid”, else “Not pyramid”.

My code is:

```
nums = int(input("Enter number: "))
num1 = nums // 10000
num2 = (nums // 1000) % 10
num3 = (nums % 1000) // 100
num4 = (nums % 100)//10
num5 = nums % 10
if num1 < num2 < num3 > num4 > num5:
    print(nums, ": is Pyramid ")
else:
    print(nums, ": is not Pyramid ")
```

I solved it this way but is it possible to make it accurate:

```
num1 = nums // 10000
num2 = (nums // 1000) % 10
num3 = (nums % 1000) // 100
num4 = (nums % 100)//10
num5 = nums % 10
```

Comment: will you consider 31543 as eligible to be announced Pyramid?

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong wit your attempts? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] so that we an understand how to offer specific help

Comment: @KunalSharma I think not, by the given definition and examples I would said that a 5 digit number with digits abcde is pyramid if a<b<c and c>d>e

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution:

My idea is that you start from either side of the number and check whether or not the number "ahead" of it is greater. I think converting the number to a *string* would be useful.

so for example:

1 2 7 4 3

1 is less than 2 and 3 is less than 4

2 is less than 7 and 4 is less than 7

then we get to the middle where we finish and can say it's a pyramid number. I hope that helps.